# Networkx maximal_independent_set function caused RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I need to measure the features of a large set of graphs. I am interested in the size of the maximal indepent set, a set of nodes such they are not adjacent to any other node within the set, and every node not in the set is adjacent to a node in the set.

I am using networkx in Python, maximal_independent_set is supposed to give me such a set (an approximation of it), but it caused this error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

when applied to graph instance `bcspwr10` which you can find here --> https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/HB/bcspwr10.html

The instance has `5300` nodes and `8271` undirected edges (loops removed).

I could modify the maximum recursion depth, but it could be dangenerous and the problem may appear again when dealing with bigger graphs. 
Does this mean I would not be able to process any graph as big as this one, neither bigger ones?